# All branches of Git lab and Image lost when Docker container exits? How to save?

Tags: docker, gitlab, branch

If my container exits then all my images got lost and their respective data as well.

Could you please answer how to save the data (Here in this case of gitlab, we have multiple branches). How to save those branches even if container exits and next time when we restart the container, I should get all my old branches back?

Comment: How are you starting the container? Are you using volumes?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit light on specific details of your workflow, but the general answer to the need for persistent data in the ephemeral container world is [**volumes**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/). Without a broader understanding of your workflow and infrastructure, it *could* be as simple as making sure that your gitlab data is in a named local volume. E.g. something you create with `docker volume` or an image that everyone uses that has a `VOLUME` location identified in the `Dockerfile` and is bind mounted to a host location at container `run` time.

Of course once you are in the world of distributed systems and orchestrating multi-node container environments, local volumes will no longer be a viable answer and you will need to investigate shared volume capabilities from a storage vendor or self-managed with NFS or some other global filesystem capabilities. A lot of good detail is provided in the [Docker volume administrative guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/) if you are new to the volume concept.